# Guayadeque won't allow to me set podcast directory

Tags: gnome, music-player, podcast

Every time I set a podcast directory and click "accept" it resets back to (none). I tried searching the internet and the only thing I could find was from the Guayadeque team back in '10 saying to install from their ppa, so I did `sudo apt-get purge guayadeque` and then installed from the ppa but the issue persists. Any ideas how to fix this? I love this music player but will have to migrate to something else if I can't get this to work. I'm running ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Shell

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your guayadeque is closed. Then edit its config file ( *~/.guayadeque/guayadeque.conf* ). Find the lines:

```
<podcasts>
  <LastPodcastUpdate value="Tue 30 Dec 2014 19:24:56 EET"/>
  <Path value="/home/[somelogin]"/>
```

and change path value `<Path value="/home/[somelogin]"/>` to something else you need.